# Undefined variable during mysql to mysqli conversion

Tags: php, mysqli

I am in the process of converting my old PHP from mysql to mysqli and am running into this error during my conversion. The code worked without throwing errors under mysql but for some reason I get the 'Undefined variable: prevcat in /xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/vluchtbijtoestel.php on line 102' error now. I've tried adding $prevcat = $cat to the variables list but that then breaks the code.

My code:

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', "xxx");
define('DB_USER', "xxx");
define('DB_PASSWORD', "xxx");
define('DB_TABLE', "xxx");

// Define your colors for the alternating rows 
$color1 = "#F0F8FF";  
$color2 = "#FFFFFF"; 
$row_count = 0;

// The procedural way
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_TABLE);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) {
    trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$query = "
    SELECT vg.gegevenID, lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappij, lvm.sm_logo, vg.vertrekdatum2, vg.vertrekluchthaven, vg.aankomstluchthaven, vg.toestel, vg.inschrijvingnmr, vlg.vliegtuignaam, vg.vluchtnmr, t.toestel AS toestelnaam, lh.luchthavencode, lh.luchthavennaam, lh.countryflag, lh2.luchthavencode AS aankomstluchthavencode, lh2.countryflag AS countryflagaankomst, vlg.erlr, vlg.firstflight, DATEDIFF(vlg.firstflight,vg.vertrekdatum2) Age1, lh2.luchthavennaam AS aankomstnaam, CONCAT(t.toestel,' ', vlg.erlr) as toestelmeterlr

    FROM (tbl_vliegtuiggegevens vlg

    INNER JOIN (tbl_luchtvaartmaatschappij lvm INNER JOIN tbl_vluchtgegevens vg ON lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID = vg.luchtvaartmaatschappij) ON (vlg.inschrijvingnmr = vg.inschrijvingnmr) AND (vlg.lvmID = lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID)) INNER JOIN tbl_toestel t ON vg.toestel = t.toestelID

    LEFT JOIN tbl_luchthaven lh
    ON vg.vertrekluchthaven = lh.luchthavenID

    LEFT JOIN tbl_luchthaven lh2
    ON vg.aankomstluchthaven = lh2.luchthavenID

    GROUP BY  lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappij, toestelmeterlr, vg.inschrijvingnmr, vg.vertrekdatum2

    ORDER BY lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappij, toestelmeterlr, vg.vertrekdatum2 DESC, vg.inschrijvingnmr; ";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ". mysqli_error($mysqli), E_USER_ERROR);

echo "
<table width='100%' border='0'>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='3'><strong>Luchtvaartmaatschappij</strong></td>
    <td width='17%'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width='12%'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width='19%'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width='28%'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width='2%'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan='3'><strong>Toestel</strong></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width='3%'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width='19%'><strong>vertrekdatum</strong></td>
    <td><strong>vliegroute</strong></td>
    <td><strong>registratie</strong></td>
    <td><strong>vliegtuignaam</strong></td>
    <td><strong>vliegtuig leeftijd op reisdatum</strong></td>
  </tr>
</table>
";

if($result) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $row_color = ($row_count % 2) ? $color1 : $color2;
    $date1 = date_create($row['firstflight']);
    $date2 = date_create($row['vertrekdatum2']);
    $interval = date_diff($date1, $date2);
    $cat = $row['luchtvaartmaatschappij'];
    $subcat = $row['toestelmeterlr'];
    $item = $row['inschrijvingnmr'];


    if($cat != $prevcat){

echo "  <table width='100%' border='0'>";
echo "  <tr>";
echo "    <td><br /><hr></td>";
echo "  </tr>";
echo "  <tr>";
echo "    <td><strong><span class='style4'><img src='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/img/logos/sm/".$row['sm_logo']."'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" .$cat. "</strong></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br /></td>";
echo "  </tr>";
echo "</table>";
        echo '<span style="color: #0A0094; font-size: 16px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'. $subcat.'</span><br />';//if the category has changed, we also want to show the new subcat
    }elseif($subcat != $prevsubcat){
        echo '<br /><span style="color: #0A0094; font-size: 16px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' .$subcat.'</span><br />';
    }
echo "  <table width='1093' border='0' cellspacing='0'>";
echo "  <tr>";
echo "    <td width='75'>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "    <td width='200' bgcolor='$row_color'>" .date("d-M-Y H:i", strtotime($row['vertrekdatum2']))."</td>";
echo "    <td width='70' bgcolor='$row_color'><img src='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/img/flags/".$row['countryflag']."'> &nbsp;&nbsp;<abbr title=\"".htmlspecialchars($row['luchthavennaam'])."\">".$row['luchthavencode']."</abbr></td>";
echo "    <td width='70' bgcolor='$row_color'> &nbsp; naar &nbsp; </td>";
echo "    <td width='130' bgcolor='$row_color'><img src='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/img/flags/".$row['countryflagaankomst']."'> &nbsp;&nbsp;<abbr title=\"".htmlspecialchars($row['aankomstnaam'])."\">".$row['aankomstluchthavencode']."</abbr></td>";
echo "    <td width='150' bgcolor='$row_color'>".$row['inschrijvingnmr']."</td>";
echo "    <td width='250' bgcolor='$row_color'>".$row['vliegtuignaam'] ."</td>";
echo "    <td width='250' bgcolor='$row_color'>" . $interval->y . " jaar en " . $interval->m." maanden </td>";
echo "  </tr>";
echo "</table>";
    $prevcat = $cat;
    $prevsubcat = $subcat;
      // Add 1 to the row count 
$row_count++; 
}
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

Comment: as the error states; I don't see where you set / assigned the `$prevcat` variable and it's unsure as to which one you should/want to use.

Comment: When I add $prevcat = $cat or try $prevcat = $row['luchtvaartmaatschappij']; then it breaks my code.

Comment: move     $prevcat = $cat;
    $prevsubcat = $subcat; after declaring $cat and $subcat

Comment: when put after declaring $cat and $subcat, it breaks the code. However, oddly, when put before the $cat and $subcat, then the code works as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

put your code .. you are using $precat and $prevsubcat in your if conditions before declaring and defining it.

```
 $prevcat = $cat;
 $prevsubcat = $subcat;
```

after

```
$cat = $row['luchtvaartmaatschappij'];
$subcat = $row['toestelmeterlr'];
```

like this

```
$cat = $row['luchtvaartmaatschappij'];
$subcat = $row['toestelmeterlr'];
$prevcat = $cat;
$prevsubcat = $subcat;
```

Comment: That did not work (I tried it previously). It broke the code. However, when put BEFORE the $cat = $row['luchtvaartmaatschappij']; then it worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Put

> $prevcat = '';
>   $prevsubcat = '';

Juste before "While" expression

Regards